# Send message to personal Chat via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I read from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#get-messages-returns-chats-in-microsoft-teams) that getting a user's Teams chats that occurred outside the scope of a team or channel (1-to-1 chat conversation), you need to use this request

```
GET /users/id/messages
```

and Teams chat messages have "IM" as their subject.

My question now is whether it is possible to send a new message to this conversation via the Graph API and that the message will be displayed on the Teams application?

I tried to reply to this message via the graph API, but the reply message was sent to Outlook, not in the Microsoft Teams application.

Comment: I do not have sufficiente reputation to comment on above answer, so here goes : If you are testing with the Graph Explorer, just remember to use POST: I was going crazy trying to send a message, just to discover I was always sending GET requests :-p

Answer (score 6):

It is now possible to send messages to personal chat(1:1) or to group chat in Microsoft Teams using Microsoft Graph API. And yes, the messages will be displayed in the Teams application using Microsoft Graph API.

Please refer the "1:1 and group chat messages" section from the below microsoft documentation link:

[chatMessage resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta)

Also, below is the graph API to send a message to any conversation you want using **Post** HTTP method :

***https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user-id}/chats/{chat-id}/messages***

To fetch {user-id} and {chat-id}, please follow the below steps using **Get** HTTP method:

1. Fetch the user id of a logged-in user or user id of other user using below graph API's:

   *https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me 

   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users*
2. Fetch the conversation/chat id of a user:

   *https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats 

   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/chats*

As of now, there is no graph API to reply to a personal chat but we can reply to any team's channel message using Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: You can reply to a 1:1 chat now. :) You just can't create new 1:1 threads yet.

Comment: Could you please send the graph API or a link to reply to 1:1 chat? I need it.

Comment: You already have the info above. :) You just need the thread id and then post to /me/chats/{thread id}/messages

Comment: @PravinDurgam How do you figure out which chat is for a specific user? I'm able to find every 1:1 chat, but I don't know which chat is for a specific user.

Comment: @Anthony, You have to first fetch user's id's via Microsoft Graph API's and then concatenate the user's ids to get the chat id like->

"19:" + User1.Id + "_" + User2.Id + "@unq.gbl.spaces"

Please note that "19:" &  "@unq.gbl.spaces" are the constants & if you construct the above string you will have chat id. Please try to do vice a versa of the user's Id's by keeping the constants same if you don't find the user's chat otherwise. This way you will be able to find which chat is for which specific user's.

Comment: @PravinDurgam Thanks. That was a lot easier to understand than your answer for some reason. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

The answer, for now, is **no**. The docs have stated

> "In both the v1 and beta endpoints, the response of `GET /users/id/messages` includes the user's Microsoft Teams chats that occurred outside the scope of a team or channel. These chat messages have "IM" as their subject."

You may submit/vote an feature request in the UserVoice or just wait the update from the Product Team.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed explanation to answers that @parvin provided if you are trying to do this using Graph Explorer. There is one difference that in this method you don't need to have user-id anymore and chat-id would suffice. Simply Post HTTP method:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chat-id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/%7Bchat-id%7D/messages)

if you don't know how to get the chat-id, pleaser refer to answer provided by Parvin. Make sure your message is in the json format and you can put that in request body.

[image]

Then you can go to "Request headers"  tab and add "Content-type" as Key and "application/json" as value.

[image]

Comment: Hello, i am using this, but i notice that when i send the message i get no notification in teams that the message has arrived

Comment: @rread: do you receive the message but not the notification or you dont event receive the message? If you dont receive the message, do you get any error?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, i did not get the alerts because i was sending the message with the same user as i had teams open.
Once i started sending the message with another user it worked